# Two 3-way dimmers on 6 LED lights - lights blink when on

Tags: lighting, led, dimmer-switch, cabling

I wired 6 LED ceiling lights, and I want to control it from two sides, so I used 3-way dimmers on both sides. Everything works, I can dim the lights from both sides, but they blink. I wired a 3-way cable from one dimmer to another, and lights from second dimmer. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use two 3-way dimmers on the same lights. A 3-way dimmer can be used in combination with a 3-way switch, to have on/off/dim at one location and on/off at the other.

But if you dim at two locations, rather than getting 0% to 100% dimming controllable from either end, you end up with a combination of the two dimmers' settings that may not make sense. The exact behavior depends on the particular electronics of the dimmers, but for LED lights and their compatible dimmers blinking is a possibility as the modulation timing of the two dimmers will not align perfectly.

Change one of the dimmers to a switch. If you must have dimming at both locations, look for a dimmer that offers a remote control option.

Comment: But I use dimmers from same manufacture, same model, bought in same store, in the same time. Modulation time should be same

Comment: Think about it like turn signals on two identical cars. Sure the timing between blinks will be the same (though even that might vary slightly because manufacturing is not perfectly consistent) but those signals might not be turned on at exactly the same time, and if you add together their total light there will be "blinks" of higher and lower total light. The way your dimmers work is more complex but you still end up with a situation where the total current getting to your lights varies periodically and causes them to blink.

Comment: I know about what you are talking, but thanks for explanation in different therms. What I was thinking, that if they are from the same line it will have the same modulation timing. But newer mind, I put 3-way switch on the one end, end it work perfect. Thanks very much.

Comment: To be very clear, this is the fault of the store that kept a straight face while selling you that stuff together.  Never buy anything there again and shop at a competent electrical or lighting supply. Yes I know you probably chose that shop because of its reputation for saving money and expected no techsupport for the low price.  I hope the appeal of that fades.  These fiascos are normal when dealing with such shops.